# Showing that 4-electric field tensor is spacelike

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, vectors

I have this question in my school assignment.

[image]
Given 4-electric field as the following: $$E^\alpha = F_{\alpha\beta}U^\beta$$
where $U^\beta$ is the 4-velocity of the observer and $F_{\alpha\beta}$ is the electromagnetic field tensor. Hence, components of the 4-electric field depend on observer. Show that $E^\alpha$ is spacelike.

If I were to expand the 3 magnetic and electric field components normally without invoking particular frame of reference, I will get the following:
$$E^\alpha E_\alpha = \gamma^2(-\frac{1}{c^2}(E\cdot u)^2 + E\cdot E + (B \cdot B)(u \cdot u) - (B \cdot u)^2 + 2(E \times u) \cdot B)$$
I can group the first 4 terms up and show that they are positive but I am not sure what to do with the last $(E \times u) \cdot B$ term.

However, another idea that I have is to choose the rest frame of the observer since magnitudes of 4 vectors are lorentz invariant, and so $U^\beta$ is just (-c, 0,0,0). In which case, I will just get
$$E'^{\alpha}E'_\alpha = E'\cdot E'$$
which is clearly positive. However, I am not sure if that is a valid argument. Also, unless I did the derivation wrongly, the $(E \times u) \cdot B$ cause the magnitude to not be lorentz invariant, since flipping the direction of velocity will only affect this term.